# Snowflake: SELECT "COLUMN" with double quotes

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a customer that their Snowflake instance require the columns name to have double quotes. Example: SELECT "CategoryName" from "lk_category" ; 
Does anyone know how to turn this feature off?

Comment: In Oracle the quotes are required when the field names match to keywords.

Comment: Because your customer created tables with columns inside double quotes they are now case sensitive and double quotes must be used to reference them. There is the [Quoted_Identifiers_Ignore_Case](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-quoted-identifiers-ignore-case) variable that can be toggled to `TRUE` for a session but it has no effect on already existing objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Snowflake [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html) does explain a bit about identifiers.

The key point is that *quoted identifiers* must be referred to exactly as they are defined. So, the following are different:

```
"ABC"
"abc"
"Abc"
```

Unquoted identifiers are case-insensitive, so the following are the same:

```
ABC
abc
Abc
```

As a bonus, these are also equivalent to:

```
"ABC"
```

because Snowflake resolves unquoted identifiers using the upper case.

If the database has already been created with quoted identifiers . . . well, you can go about changing it.

Snowflake has identified this as a problem. You can turn off the quoted behavior by setting the [QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-quoted-identifiers-ignore-case) parameter.

Answer (score 1):

For your question:

```sql
SELECT """CategoryName""" FROM lk_category
```

…is the answer. I had a similar issue with double pivot tables.

Please check it using:

```sql
Describe View/Table Table/View_Name
```

We will get the list of Column Names, If a field name with double quote Ex:"Name" is present.

Then to select it we should use extra quotes as escape characters.