# How to SELECT COL_"NAME" in Snowflake ? (COLUMN name containing double quote)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know this is very bad naming practice, but I am not the owner of the table...

I need to run :

```
SELECT COL_"NAME"
FROM TABLE
```

where COL_"NAME" is the name of the column, containing double quotes.

I tried :

```
SELECT COL_""NAME""
FROM TABLE

SELECT COL_\"NAME\"
FROM TABLE
```

But nothing works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417211/snowflake-select-column-with-double-quotes answers your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Identifier Requirements](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#identifier-requirements):

> **To use the double quote character inside a quoted identifier, use two quotes.**

To access column: `COL_"NAME"`

```
SELECT "COL_""NAME"""
FROM TABLE;
```