# How to add double quotes for Varchar values with Columns and Values from Snowflake DB

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

While I am reading from the Snowflake DB, I need to read columns and values for Varchar fields. Something like the following: `select varchar_col1, varchar_col2, numeric_col3 from my_table`

```
varchar_col1          varchar_col2             numeric_col3
 
test_value1           test_value2                 99999
```

I want to output something like following:

```
"varchar_col1"       "varchar_col2"         numeric_col3

 "test_value1"        "test_value2"             99999
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this? I tried various ways but was unable to do so. For example, I tried to use this [Snowflake: SELECT "COLUMN" with double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417211/snowflake-select-column-with-double-quotes).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the varchar to a variant to add double quotes, or you can concatenate the double quotes with the column values as Himanshu showed.

As I understand, you also want column names in double quotes. For this, you need to surround the column name with double quotes while escaping the double quotes belonging to the name:

varchar_col1 -> """varchar_col1"""

```
select varchar_col1::variant """varchar_col1""", '"' ||  varchar_col2 || '"' """varchar_col2""", numeric_col3 "numeric_col3"
from values
('test_value1', 'test_value2',99999) t(varchar_col1, varchar_col2, numeric_col3);

+----------------+----------------+--------------+
| "varchar_col1" | "varchar_col2" | numeric_col3 |
+----------------+----------------+--------------+
| "test_value1"  | "test_value2"  |        99999 |
+----------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

this may work for you.

```
select '"' ||  varchar_col1 as varchar_col1 , '"' ||  varchar_col2 || '"' as varchar_col2, '"' ||  numeric_col3 || '"' as numeric_col3
from (                         
 select  column1 as varchar_col1, column2 as varchar_col2, column3 as numeric_col3 from values
('test_value1', 'test_value2',99999)
  );
```